# Inno Setup Font Issue on Swedish Windows 10

Tags: fonts, installation, inno-setup

I have a well running Inno Setup installer file, that has been behaving very nicely for several years.

One of its nicest behaviours is the ability to install fonts, this works fine on all Windows 10 OS's I have tried so far, except a Swedish Windows 10 (Enterprise and Pro).

On a Swedish Windows 10 nothing is placed in the default Windows font folder. I can reproduce this error on different machines running Windows 10 with Swedish localization. The installer script works on Windows 7 with Swedish localization. It also works on Danish and Norwegian Windows 10 installations.

```
Source: "..\Components\Fonts\IDACodHM.TTF"; DestDir: {fonts}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall; FontInstall: "IDA Codabar HR Med"
Source: "..\Components\Fonts\IDACodHS.TTF"; DestDir: {fonts}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall; FontInstall: "IDA Codabar HR Short"
Source: "..\Components\Fonts\IDACodHT.TTF"; DestDir: {fonts}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall; FontInstall: "IDA Codabar HR Tall"
Source: "..\Components\Fonts\IDACod_M.TTF"; DestDir: {fonts}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall; FontInstall: "IDA Codabar Med"
Source: "..\Components\Fonts\IDACod_S.TTF"; DestDir: {fonts}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall; FontInstall: "IDA Codabar Short"
```

I'm allowed to copy the fonts into another folder on the machine, but then the user has to install these fonts manually. I can try creating a .Net based installation app, with just this purpose, but I think Inno Setup should be able to handle this, somehow.

I have updated to the latest Inno Setup version 5.5.8 and the error is still there.

Comment: Show us a log of the installer (`setup.exe /log=setup.log`)

Comment: 2016-04-07 09:39:39.999   -- File entry --
2016-04-07 09:39:39.999   Dest filename: C:\Windows\Fonts\IDACodHM.TTF
2016-04-07 09:39:39.999   Time stamp of our file: 2016-01-06 13:20:26.000
2016-04-07 09:39:39.999   Dest file exists.
2016-04-07 09:39:39.999   Skipping due to "onlyifdoesntexist" flag.
etc... will try to remove the flag, but the fonts are not visible

Comment: Can you rather try to remove the installed font and reinstall?

Comment: Using Flag IgnoreVersion
2016-04-07 09:52:51.660   -- File entry --
2016-04-07 09:52:51.660   Dest filename: C:\Windows\Fonts\IDACodHM.TTF
2016-04-07 09:52:51.660   Time stamp of our file: 2016-01-06 13:20:26.000
2016-04-07 09:52:51.660   Dest file exists.
2016-04-07 09:52:51.660   Time stamp of existing file: 2016-01-06 13:20:26.000
2016-04-07 09:52:51.660   Installing the file.
2016-04-07 09:52:51.707   Successfully installed the file.
2016-04-07 09:52:51.707   Registering file as a font ("IDA Codabar HR Med (TrueType)")

Answer (score 2):

There is a Windows 10 option to hide Fonts based on Language settings, Doh!!!

This seemed to work on the Enterprise edition, not on the pro version.

In Explorer open C:\Windows\fonts choose from the menu presented to the left.

Font type settings (2 option) and uncheck the first checkbox, hide fonts based on language settings

Press ok, and now the missing font should appear inside the font folder.

After testing again it seems necessary to click the link to reset font settings to default and then remove the checkmark...

[Screen dump of settings picture](http://fud.community.services.support.microsoft.com/Fud/FileDownloadHandler.ashx?fid=12084783-6b5d-4bc9-977d-b2b5a4c7bb28)

Comment: Sure, done. Reading about fonts on the web it also appears that Windows firewall must be enabled to being allowed to install fonts. That can conflict with AV software, that tends to also like to be firewall.